# Can I use Chef for Desired State Configuration (DSC) of MSIs?

Tags: windows, chef

I am trying to figure out how to work with MSIs using Chef. What I would like is to have something where I can specify a product, version, and download link. Chef would then query the MSI database, check against version, and not a match, download and install via the link. It seems like building blocks are present in Chef, but I can't quite figure out how they tie together. Is it possible to do this?

Thanks!
Erick